# Failed to write/update a key in HKLM using TRegistry

Tags: windows-10, registry, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am trying to write/update a value in HKLM using `TRegistry`, but never succeed when I open the registry using `OpenKey()` (it always returns false).

My application is 32bit.  I write the code in C++Builder 10.3. My OS is Windows 10.

Here is my code:

```
BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
BOOL result=FALSE;
IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);
long flags = KEY_WRITE;
if (bIsWow64) flags |= KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
TRegistry *sfReg = new TRegistry(flags);
sfReg->RootKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
UnicodeString mykey="software\\MyName\\MyAppName\\";
sfReg->Access=flags;
result=sfReg->OpenKey(mykey,true);
if(result)
{
    if(MainForm->usermode==USER_TEACHER)
    {
        sfReg->WriteString("tPswd",Edit2->Text);
    }
    else
    {
        sfReg->WriteString("fPswd",Edit2->Text);
    }
}
delete sfReg;
p->CommaText=MainForm->pLang->Strings[LANG_START+134];
MessageDlg(p->Strings[1], mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
Close();
```

Comment: What is the value of [`sfReg->LastError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.Registry.TRegistry.LastError) when `sfReg->OpenKey()` fails? Typically, only an admin can write to keys in the HKLM hive. Is your app running with admin privileges? Since you are clearly writing to your own custom key, why are you using HKLM instead of HKCU?

Comment: @remy-lebeau Value of LastError is 5. I have checked my app running not in admin privilages. I chose HKLM because the application (in the same PC) will be used by several levels of users.

Comment: Error 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, which makes sense if you are running without admin rights. So, either make your app (or at least your Registry code) run as an admin, or else an admin will have to grant non-admin access to your key.